# "document.getElementById" writes to textbox Id

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2  control-label">Ürün Adı</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="urun_adi" name="urun_adi" onchange="CBtoTB()">
        <?php
            do {  
        ?>
        <?php 
         if($DUZEN["urun_adi"]==$row_rs_urunler['Id']){
            $selecturun='selected';
         }else{
            $selecturun='';
         }?>
        <option value="
            <?php echo $row_rs_urunler['Id']; ?>" 
            <?php echo $selecturun; ?> >
            <?php echo $row_rs_urunler['urun_adi']?>
        </option>
        <?php
          } while ($row_rs_urunler = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_urunler));
              $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_urunler);
              if($rows > 0) {
                 mysql_data_seek($rs_urunler, 0);
                 $row_rs_urunler = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_urunler);
              }
        ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is javascript method

```
<script>
    function CBtoTB()
    {
document.getElementById("fatura_urun2").value=document.getElementById("urun_adi").value
    }
</script>
```

here is input

```
<td><input id="fatura_urun2"/></td>
```

These code work, but prints the input 'id number'. I want to write the name of the product. Thanks to those who suggested it.

Comment: What element does the name of the product come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function CBtoTB()
    {
var urun_adi = document.getElementById("urun_adi");
document.getElementById("fatura_urun2").value=urun_adi.options[urun_adi.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

Instead of selecting the value, select the text of selected option.